# Redirections old site to new problems (Prestashop)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, prestashop

I have a little problem with the redirection of my old site to the new one.
The new domain : https://www.vin-saintchinian.shop
The old domain : https://www.vin-saintchinian.com

all redirections works well except one :
https://www.vin-saintchinian.com make an error when we go on it "inaccessible site".

As it a prestashop site, i also tried to use the .htaccess of the old site but it don't work

part of code i tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
Redirect 301 / https://www.vin-saintchinian.shop/
RedirectPermanent / https://www.vin-saintchinian.shop/
</IfModule>
```

also :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?vin-saintchinian\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://www.vin-saintchinian.shop/$1 [L,R=301]
```

And little derivations of that lines.

I've also tried with OVH's redirections (my site is heberged by them) and i know its kind of dirty redirection but it's to see if it works.

So the problematic url is : https://www.vin-saintchinian.com (and https://vin-saintchinian.com).
to resume its the redirections with HTTPS protocol, the HTTP one work.

Do you have a idea ?
Thank you in advance and have a good day.

Comment: "all redirections works well except one" - Not sure what you mean by "all", but _none_ of the redirections "work" AFAICT?! You don't appear to have a valid SSL cert for the old domain, so the _browser_ is triggering the warning you are seeing: `NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`

Comment: "i also tried to use the .htaccess of the old site" - how else were you trying to do this?

Comment: @MrWhite Hi, Yeah sorry i wasn't clear in my explain :/ 
Its all of HTTPS redirections that didn't work, so i checked if i had a valid SSL on my old domain (like you said) and yes i have one actually. (Let's Encrypt). 

For your second comment, i said i tried with OVH (we can do some redirection on the admin panel of the web hosting) after that the redirection in the .htaccess  wont work for https, but it hasn't solved my problem